# Essa tag não tem [lógica]. E muito menos [logica]

Tags: debate, tags

Esbarrei nessas duas tags:

[lógica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/l%c3%b3gica) - 36 perguntas no momento, sem wiki.

[logica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logica) - 6 perguntas no momento, sem wiki.

Bem, a tag [lógica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/l%c3%b3gica) é uma tag sem lógica nenhuma, pois o termo "lógica" é um termo muito genérico, podendo ser lógica de programação, lógica booleana, portas lógicas, lógica construtivista, lógica racional, lógica filosófica...

Já a tag [logica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logica) nem se fala, não há lógica nenhuma em uma tag com erro ortográfico.

Comment: Acho que era boa ideia eliminar as duas...

Comment: As tags eu não sei, mas os trocadilhos tão começando a ficar legais :) Não deveríamos ter uma meta-tag para essas solicitações?

Comment: @Math Acho que sim.

Comment: Deveríamos era ter uma ferramenta de aniquilação de tags, @Math. Acho que nem o Gabe tem isso.

Comment: Ressucitaram a tag a algum tempo e inclusive fizeram o favor de fazer um edição de uso meio *nonsense*, se me permitirem irei colaborar para eliminar, porque mesmo que ela tenha algum uso, no geral é quase totalmente mal usada.